# DCV Viewer on Fedora 38 instalation error

Tags: fedora, aws, dnf

I'm trying to install the Nice DCV 2023 Client such that I can remote into my remote workstation. [Several installers are available](https://download.nice-dcv.com/latest.html), for distros like Ret Hat, SUSE, Ubuntu, but not for Fedora.

Nevertheless, I expected that I could install the .rpm (RedHat) version, as that used to work for previous Fedora editions. I downloaded the Rat Hat 9, CentOS9, Rocky Linux 9 (x86_64) edition and installed it using:

```
[user@device] sudo dnf install 'nice-dcv-viewer-el9.x86_64.rpm'
Laatste metadata-expiratie-check: 0:11:14 geleden op wo 13 sep 2023 09:20:46 CEST.
Fout: 
 Probleem: tegenstrijdige verzoeken
  - nothing provides libicuuc.so.67()(64bit) needed by nice-dcv-viewer-2023.0.5629-1.el9.x86_64 from @commandline
(probeer '--skip-broken' toe te voegen om niet-installeerbare pakketten over te slaan)
```

which through an exception which I'm not familiar with, I'll translate it to English:

```
[user@device] sudo dnf install 'nice-dcv-viewer-el9.x86_64.rpm'
lLast metadata-expiratie-check: 0:11:14 past on wen 13 sep 2023 09:20:46 CEST.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libicuuc.so.67()(64bit) needed by nice-dcv-viewer-2023.0.5629-1.el9.x86_64 from @commandline
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

I think that it means that dnf has no way to install the prerequisite `libicuuc.so` of version 67.

I did try the other installers, hoping that one of them either ships with the prerequisite or does not require it altogether, but no luck.

Does anyone know how to obtain the prerequisite or how to avoid it and successfully install the DCV viewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Nevertheless, I expected that I could install the .rpm (RedHat) version, as that used to work for previous Fedora editions.

That worked only by luck. Fedora is *not* binary compatible.

You typically solve this by simply setting up a podman container with access to your host's display, based on an actually binary compatible distro, and install things there.

Comment: Many thanks, I was afraid of this. I have no rights on the remote (it is managed by a research institute) and can only install software on my client device. Do I understand correctly that the best would then be running a RedHat VM (or similar) on fedora, and use that to access the remote with DCV.

Comment: Well this is all local anyway, just as your attempt to install directly from rpm. Not a VM, but a container.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work. Specifically, I installed an Ubuntu 22.04 using [this manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75423497/with-the-toolbox-container-tool-can-i-run-an-ubuntu-toolbox-on-top-of-a-fedora) and installed DCV there. Now I can launch it directly from Fedora with: ```toolbox run -c ubuntu-toolbox dcvviewer```, to make things easy I also created a desktop entry with that run command.

Comment: Nice! Do you want to post this as an answer to your own question, maybe? I'd upvote a good answer that shows how you addressed the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @MarcusMüller helped to the right track. The following procedure should help install Nice DCV viewer on Fedora. A similar approach should also work on other unsupported platforms.

1. Install `toolbox`and `podman` if not preinstalled using `sudo dnf install toolbox podman`
2. Download Nice DCV viewer installer for Ubuntu 22.04 from the [official website](https://download.nice-dcv.com/latest.html).
3. Create a podman container with Ubuntu 22.04 which is a supported platform

   - Create a file named Dockerfile in your home directory
   - Add the following text to that file

     ```
     FROM docker.io/ubuntu:22.04
     RUN apt-get update; apt-get -y install libcap2-bin; apt-get clean
     ```
   - Create the required image with podman

     ```
     podman build -t ubuntu-toolbox .
     ```
   - Create the toolbox

     ```
     toolbox create --image ubuntu-toolbox ubuntu-toolbox
     ```
4. Install Nice DCV viewer in the toolbox

   - Enter the toolbox

     ```
     toolbox enter ubuntu-toolbox
     ```
   - Navigate to the downloads folder

     ```
     cd Downloads
     ```
   - Obtain superuser rights (I had `sudo` problems thus used `su`)

     ```
     su
     ```
   - Install the Nice DCV viewer

     ```
     dpkg -i nice-dcv-viewer_amd64.ubuntu2204.deb
     ```
   - If any errors occur, one might have to repair the `apt` environment, and then try installing the program again.

     ```
     sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
     ```
   - Test launching the program with the command, the program should then open with its normal UI.

     ```
     dcvviewer
     ```
   - Exit the container using the `exit` command twice or start a new cli.
5. Make a desktop entry that automatically lauches the program that is within the container.

   - Run the following command to start Nice DCV from fedora to test the setup

     ```
     toolbox run -c ubuntu-toolbox dcvviewer
     ```
   - Create a desktop entry by creating a text file named `com.nicesoftware.DcvViewer.desktop` at `~/.local/share/applications` containing the following:

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Name=NICE DCV Viewer
     Comment=NICE DCV Viewer
     Exec=toolbox run -c ubuntu-toolbox dcvviewer %U
     TryExec=dcvviewer
     Terminal=false
     Type=Application
     Icon=remote-desktop
     MimeType=application/x-dcv;x-scheme-handler/dcv
     Categories=GNOME;GTK;Network;
     Hidden=false
     NoDisplay=false
     StartupNotify=false
     ```

That's it, you should be able to find it in your applications' menu now.